# How does bacteriorhodopsin differ from the rhodopsin present in mammalian eyes?

Tags: pigmentation

In my high school textbook, it is written that they are similar. So, I was just curious to know about this.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We recommend all posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to be a _simple Q&A site_, but rather a site that promotes **self-learning** with some expert help along the way. Please take a moment to edit your post with this **_additional detail_**, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thank you for being a part of this SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although they are similar in both bacteriorhodopsins  and rhodopsins being **[retinal-binding proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinylidene_protein)**, the similarity in their [amino acid sequence](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-4604-3_16) is very limited.

The key difference between them is that rhodopsin is a [G-protein-coupled receptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_protein-coupled_receptor), and this is not the case with bacteriorhodopsin. A quick Google search on *Bacteriorhodopsin vs Rhodopsin* will send you to a Wikipedia article that says:

> Bacteriorhodopsin belongs to the **microbial rhodopsins**. They have similarities to vertebrate rhodopsins, the pigments that sense light in the retina. Rhodopsins also contain retinal; however, the functions of rhodopsin and bacteriorhodopsin are different, and there is limited similarity in their amino acid sequences. Both *rhodopsin and bacteriorhodopsin* belong to the **7TM receptor** family of proteins, but rhodopsin ***is*** a G protein-coupled receptor and bacteriorhodopsin ***is not***.

A very good paper if you would like to know more about the two is by **H. Gobind Khorana** on the *[Two light-transducing membrane proteins](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/90/4/1166.full.pdf)*.